# (Bootstrap contact form) possible to email back only fields that are filled in?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm wondering if it is possible for a contact form to **email me only the information of the fields which have been filled in**?

So that if there is a list of items with a quantity field next to it (please see screenshot below), only the item names with the quantity field filled in will be returned in email. This is so if I have an item list of 100 items, the email will not need to contain a list of 100 items when only one item's quantity field was filled in.

Here's a screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGltA.jpg)

I'm using templates for contact form, and the codes which I've added are below.

On the website contact form page, the codes for each item is like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
                          <label class="col-lg-3 control-label" for="acelite">Acelite</label>
                          <div class="col-lg-3">
                            <div class="input-group">
                              <div class="input-group-addon">Qty</div>
                              <input type="number" min="0" class="form-control" id="acelite" placeholder="0">
                            </div>
                          </div>
```

The js code:

```
  // get values from FORM
            var name = $("input#name").val();
            var email = $("input#email").val();
            var phone = $("input#phone").val();
            var acelite = $("input#acelite").val();
            var acrylico = $("input#acrylico").val();
            var anges = $("input#anges").val();
            var ante = $("input#ante").val();
            var message = $("textarea#message").val();
            var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
            // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
            if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
                firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
            }
            $.ajax({
                url: "././mail/contact_me.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    name: name,
                    phone: phone,
                    email: email,
                    acelite: acelite,
                    acrylico: acrylico,
                    anges: anges,
                    ante: ante,
                    message: message
                },
```

And the php part:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$acelite = $_POST['acelite'];
$acrylico = $_POST['acrylico'];
$anges = $_POST['anges'];
$ante = $_POST['ante'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
```

Also, if there are 100 items, do I need to create variables for all 100 items like what I've done above?

e.g. 
`var acelite = $("input#acelite").val();` 
and `$acelite = $_POST['acelite'];`

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can loop through the $_POST variable and build your email based on it.

Comment: Ok thank you! I'll look into it. And also just the question down the bottom which you probably missed: if there are 100 items, do I need to create variables for all 100 items like what I've done so far? Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: Depends, if you can do, whatever you want to do within the loop (like adding text to a variable) than not. But if you can't.. hmm well can't think of a thing when you can't. Mostly it is possible to do anything in the foreach loop. It might get a bit complex but that's another point.

Comment: I see, thanks for your reply! I'll try a different style for the form. This will be too complicated for my coding level :P